# Change oh-my-zsh theme when ssh is run

Tags: terminal, zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

I have Oh-my-zsh installed on iterm2. How can I make my terminal change theme whenever ssh is run? It would be nice if the script also changes the background to one of the presets imported.

I am a complete bash noob. Please explain in newbie language.

Answer (score 18):

The first thing you need to know is that *.zshrc* is a script that is run just before you open a new session on zsh. So, providing that zsh is your default shell, when you open a terminal on your local machine, it runs *.zshrc*. When you open a ssh session to that machine, it runs *.zshrc* too!

Inside *.zshrc* you can find that piece of code commented:

```
# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi
```

You can use this example to achieve your goal, just this way:

```
if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
  ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
else
  ZSH_THEME="agnoster"
fi
```

Where *robbyrussell* will be used on your ssh sessions, and *agnoster* for the rest. So just substitute the line where you set your theme for the if/else statement above, and customize it

Answer (score 6):

You could prepend the host name to your prompt.

Following this [gist](https://gist.github.com/SteelPangolin/187c7148b90e04f0855f)

Just paste the contents of this file on:

```
~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/robbyrussell.zsh-theme
```

Then basically on your local machine:

[image]

And on you remote machine:

[image]

In my case, ded12 is the hostname of my remote and I only changed the theme files on my remote, if I changed it locally it would have my local hostname also prepending the prompt